# Mustache conditional statement (if/else) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache, templating

Trying to come to grips with Mustache... the problem here is that the conditional 'if/else' is not working as expected. I am checking in the data if a user is french... if they are then show true, else show false.

**Problem**

Mustache is completely ignoring the conditional and displaying both true and false for each table row.

[image]

**My code**

My markup

```
<!--  -->
<h3>Looping through people</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <template id="template2">
        {{#users}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{age}}</td>
                <td>{{language}}</td>
                {{#is_french}}
                    <td>True</td>
                {{/is_french}}
                {{^is_french}}
                    <td>False</td>
                {{/is_french}}
            </tr>
        {{/users}}
    </template>
    <tbody id="table2"></tbody>
</table>
<!--  -->
```

My jQuery

```
$(function(){


    /**
     * conditional data
     */
    template = $('#template2').html();
    data = {
        'users': [{
                name: 'John',
                age: 22,
                language: 'French',
                is_french: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'Billy',
                age: 33,
                language: 'Anglaise',
                is_french: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'Michael',
                age: 77,
                language: 'Cambodian',
                is_french: false,
        }]
    };
    $('#table2').html(Mustache.render(template, data));


});
```

**Question**

Why is the if/else not working here?

EDIT: Here is my entire document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <h1 class="text-center">Mustache Examples</h1>

            <!--  -->
            <h3>Looping through people</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Language</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <template id="template2">
                    {{#users}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{name}}</td>
                            <td>{{age}}</td>
                            <td>{{language}}</td>
                            {{#is_french}}
                                <td>True</td>
                            {{/is_french}}
                            {{^is_french}}
                                <td>False</td>
                            {{/is_french}}
                        </tr>
                    {{/users}}
                </template>
                <tbody id="table2"></tbody>
            </table>
            <!--  -->

        </div>


        <script>

        $(function(){

            /**
             * conditional data
             */
            template = $('#template2').html();
            data = {
                'users': [{
                        name: 'John',
                        age: 22,
                        language: 'French',
                        is_french: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Billy',
                        age: 33,
                        language: 'Anglaise',
                        is_french: false,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Michael',
                        age: 77,
                        language: 'Cambodian',
                        is_french: false,
                }]
            };
            $('#table2').html(Mustache.render(template, data));

        });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You provided `template3`, while using `template2` in view. There is no `is_french` usage in `template2`.

Comment: My bad! So sorry about that, copied the wrong block!

Comment: Interesting, but the code you've posted is totally OK, mustache template is fine, and it rendered as supposed. There should be the mistake in another part of code. Could you create fiddle where this problem reproduces?

Comment: Trying to get a fiddle going... I updated my OP with the entire document. Strange indeed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/poeama5u/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem of using `template` tag, which is actually [HTML5 template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). Using hashes in it makes browser think that this is document fragment. Seems like nested document fragments corrupt Mustache template.

Just change it to `script` tag, as in mustache manual.

```
<script id="template2" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  {{#users}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{age}}</td>
      <td>{{language}}</td>                            
      {{#is_french}}
          <td>True</td>
      {{/is_french}}
      {{^is_french}}
          <td>False</td>
      {{/is_french}}
    </tr>
  {{/users}}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh snap, that is great!